# Submission condition for ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have an html form, and an ajax script that sends it without refreshing the page, I also have a check that two identical post dates do not get into the database, but when I click on submit, it still writes "form was submitted", help me fix it

Here is my script

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('#my_form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/main/store',
            data: $('#my_form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
        });
      });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: This is an issue with the server-side code - The output in the client depends upon what you send back from the server. If there is a duplicate send a response that makes the ajax callback display a different message

Comment: I wanted to know how to make a condition for displaying a message in ajax if a record already exists

Comment: I understand what you want to do - I'm suggesting that you send different responses from your PHP script ( `/main/store` ) based upon the result of the date check. Then change the callback (ajax callback) to process that response data and thus control what is `alerted` to the user

Comment: Ok, I will try, thank you

Comment: If you add the PHP code that checks the date it will be easier to show the approach I tried to describe

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the data you send in the ajax request or how you process the request at the server you will need to adapt the following semi-pseudo code to suit your needs or simply design your own solution using some of this.

Essentially the ajax callback should receive data from the server. In your code the callback has no arguments supplied - add a variable in `success: function () {...` similar to `success: function(r) {...` so the response from the server is now assigned to `r`

With that response you can now display a different message to the user based upon the value of `r`.
For instance:

```
<?php
    /****************
        /main/store
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
    
        require 'dbconn.php';
    
    
        /* example pseudo function to test date */
        function date_is_duplicate( $date ){
            global $db; // your db connection variable
            
            $sql='select * from `TABLE` where `DATEFIELD`=?';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$date);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $rows=$stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            
            /*
                ..... etc, etc, etc and return a value to be used in ajax callback 
                If there are ZERO rows send ZERO as response - or more than ZERO means duplicate
            */
            return $rows;
        }
    
    
        /* Do the Duplicate Date search tests */
        $result=date_is_duplicate( $_POST['date'] );
        if( $result ) exit( $result );
        else{
            /* 
                do other exciting things - add to db etc etc but SEND a response to the
                ajax callback so that it can display the correct message.
                send ZERO as response.
            */
        }
    }
?>
```

And then, the modified javascript that has a response variable that helps fork the program logic:-

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/main/store',
            data: $('#my_form').serialize(),
            success:function(r) {
            
                let message='OK, form was submitted';
                if( Number(r)===1 )message='Bogus, duplicate date detected';
            
                alert(message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

A far more robust data structure to send back would be JSON rather than a single integer - this was hastily cobbled together to illustrate the concept. With JSON you can design greater complexity into the solution